# What can we say about this function when it approaches zero from above?

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Define the function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-x\right)^2}I_{\{x: x \ne \frac{1}{n}\}}(x)$$.

What can we say about this function as it approaches zero? I think it is pretty clear that $\limsup\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\infty$, this is because no matter how close we are to zero, we can choose an $n^*$ closer to zero, and then approach it. But what about $\liminf\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$?, is it possible to see what this is? As we get closer to zero, the tail in the sum has elements of $(1/n-x)^2$ that becomes very small, but $2^n$ becomes very big, so they might cancel them out?

Comment: What is $I_{...}(x)$ ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It is the indicator function.  $I_A(x) = 1$ is $x \in A$, and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Take $x$ to be half way between $\frac1{m+1}$ and $\frac1m$.  Then if $m$ is large enough,
$$ \left|x-\frac1n\right| \ge \frac1{3m^2} \quad \text{if $n \ge \sqrt m$},$$
and
$$ \left|x-\frac1n\right| \ge \frac{1-\epsilon} n  \quad \text{if $n < \sqrt m$}.$$
Then
$$ \sum_{n \ge \sqrt m} 2^{-n} \left(x-\frac1n\right)^{-2} \le \frac{18 m^4}{2^{\sqrt m}} \to 0  \quad \text{as $m \to \infty$,} $$
and
$$ \sum_{n < \sqrt m} 2^{-n} \left(x-\frac1n\right)^{-2} \le \frac1{(1-\epsilon)^2}\sum_{n \le \sqrt m} \frac{n^2}{2^{n}} . $$
So
$$ \liminf_{x\to 0+} f(x) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{n}} .$$
But clearly
$$ f(x) \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{n}} .$$
Hence
$$ \liminf_{x\to 0+} f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{n}} = 6.$$

Answer (score 0):

For odd $n\in \Bbb N$ let $x_n=n^{-1}-4^{-n}.$ Then $x_n\ne m^{-1}$ for any $m\in \Bbb N$ (Why?) and $f(x_n)>2^{-n}(n^{-1}-x_n)^{-2}=2^n.$

I think your attempt to explain why $\lim_{y\to 0^+}\sup_{x\in (0,y)}f(x)=\infty$ is vague.

Comment: Why do you need to show $x_n \ne m^{-1}$.  You don't use those other terms anyway.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith . You need to know that $x_n$ is not the reciprocal of a natural number so that $x_n$ is in the domain of $f$.

Comment: But the definition of $f$ includes the $I_{x \ne \frac1n}$, so $\frac1n$ is in the domain of $f$.